# Block only works if it is the second parameter

Tags: ruby, block

I am making rspec tests pass. These are the tests:

```
describe "adder" do
  it "adds one to the value returned by the default block" do
    adder do
      5
    end.should == 6
  end
  it "adds 3 to the value returned by the default block" do
    adder(3) do
      5
    end.should == 8
  end
end
```

This passes the tests:

```
def adder(n=1,&block)
  yield + n
end
```

while this does not:

```
def adder(&block,n=1)
  yield + n
end
```

It works only if I pass the block as the second argument. Why is this? Is this always the case with blocks, or is this just for this particular case?

Comment: because its the way ruby works. You can pass lambdas as args wherever you want though

Comment: Great! so it's a rule. Okay so blocks can only be passes as last arguments, or what is the exact formal rule I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

Comment: The second version is a syntax error for me (ruby 2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that you can pass an unnamed block, which is very commonly done in Ruby.

```
adder { 41 }
```

And you can remove the `&block` argument altogether.

Named blocks must be the last argument.

All methods can take a block.  Most simply do not do anything with a block.

[Documentation on Methods from ruby-doc.org for Ruby 2.2.0 states:](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#documentation)

> There are three types of arguments when sending a message, the
>   positional arguments, keyword (or named) arguments and the block
>   argument.

Answer (score 0):

Only the last parameter can be used to capture a method's block. The general argument format (in order) is

1. Mandatory arguments
2. Optional arguments
3. Splat
4. More mandatory arguments
5. Keyword arguments
6. Block argument

Note that the block argument is only needed for capturing the method's block as a Proc object, so you can leave it out of your `adder` method. Every Ruby method implicitly accepts a block.